# sqoop import using free form query

Tags: sql, sqoop

```sh
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre \
--username training \
--password training \
--target-dir /axl172930/loudacre/pset1 \
--split-by acct_num \
--query 'SELECT first_name,last_name,acct_num,city,state from accounts a 
JOIN (SELECT account_id, count(device_id) as num_of_devices 
      FROM accountdevice group by account_id 
      HAVING count(device_id) = 1)d ON a.acct_num = d.account_id 
      WHERE $CONDITIONS'
```

The question is as follows: Import the first name, last name, account number, city and state of the accounts having exactly 1 device.

`accounts` and `accountdevice` are tables. When I used the `distinct` keyword in the count function I was getting different number of records. Which approach is correct for the above question? Please suggest if you can get the answer without using a subquery.

Comment: **Note:** I formatted the code for clarity. The original question has the entire query as one line.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query should satisfy your requirement:

```
SELECT a.first_name,a.last_name,a.acct_num,a.city,a.state,count(d.device_id)
FROM accounts a JOIN num_of_devices d on a.acct_num = d.account_id
GROUP BY a.acct_num HAVING count(d.device_id) = 1);
```